# How to store time created in MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I want to store the timestamp which a row was inserted into a MySQL table with the row, to be later compared to other times. What's the best field type for this and what's the best way to insert the row with the timestamp in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. This will create a TIMESTAMP field that is set on INSERT, but not on UPDATE.

Comment: When I retrieve the value with PHP, how do I make it return as the number of seconds since the reference date?

Comment: @Chetan, SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(updated_at) as updated_at FROM Table;

Comment: In your `SELECT` query, add another column.. `now()-timestamp_column as difference`

Comment: @vava: That returns the unix timestamp value, not the difference in seconds since the current date.

Comment: I have a `SELECT *` query and I access the return values by index in the array that is generated. Is there any way to use the same `SELECT *` query without having to have a seperate `now()-timestamp_column as difference` query?

Comment: Never mind, I can just use `strtotime()` to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Use TIMESTAMP as the field type. All TIMESTAMP field types will have CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as the default (which is a alias for NOW())

While adding a record, write `''` to that field - it will take the default time as the value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTime datatype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) for the column, the [NOW() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) to set the current time and the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) if you need to compare it using PHP